# Symfony3 error changing DateTime on entity with Ajax

Tags: ajax, doctrine-orm, symfony

### I want to change the date of a doctrine entity but the change is not saved.

With ajax a call this function:

```
public function relancerTicketAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    if (!$this->get('session')->get('compte'))
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('accueil'));

    $isAjax = $request->isXMLHttpRequest();

    if ($isAjax)
    {
        $ticket = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('CommonBundle:Ticket')->find($id);
        $ticket->setDateButoire($ticket->getDateButoire()->modify('+7 day'));
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => true, 'date' => $ticket->getDateButoire()->format('d-m-Y'));
        return new Response(json_encode($response));
    }
    $response = array("code" => 0, "success" => false);
    return new Response(json_encode($response));
}
```

When I alert the result I get the right new value, but after reload there is no change saved.

This function called in the same conditions works:

```
public function traiterTicketAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    if (!$this->get('session')->get('compte'))
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('accueil'));

    $isAjax = $request->isXMLHttpRequest();

    if ($isAjax)
    {
        $compte = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('CommonBundle:Compte')->find($this->get('session')->get('compte')->getId());

        $ticket = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('CommonBundle:Ticket')->find($id);
        $ticket->addDestinataire($compte);
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => true);
        return new Response(json_encode($response));
    }
    $response = array("code" => 0, "success" => false);
    return new Response(json_encode($response));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the [docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html)

> When calling EntityManager#flush() Doctrine computes the changesets of
>   all the currently managed entities and saves the differences to the
>   database. In case of object properties (@Column(type=”datetime”) or
>   @Column(type=”object”)) these comparisons are always made BY
>   REFERENCE. That means the following change will NOT be saved into the
>   database:

```
/** @Entity */
class Article
{
    /** @Column(type="datetime") */
    private $updated;

    public function setUpdated()
    {
        // will NOT be saved in the database
        $this->updated->modify("now");
    }
}
```

So, in your case I suggest to clone dateButoire, like this

```
$ticket = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('CommonBundle:Ticket')->find($id);
$newDateButoire = clone $ticket->getDateButoire();
$ticket->setDateButoire($newDateButoire->modify('+7 day'));
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```